# Can Armadillo efficiently multiply sparse-by-sparse and sparse-by-dense matrices into a dense result?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am using Armadillo for some linear algebra problems. It has `SpMat<float>` for sparse matrices and `Mat<float>` for dense matrices.

Suppose I have sparse matrices`S_a` and `S_b`, and a dense matrix `D`. I need to compute the produces `S_a*S_b` and `S_a*D`, the results will be dense in both cases.

I can convert the sparse matrices into dense matrices and then multiply, but that will be inefficient (these matrices are very large). Is there a way to tell Armadillo to store the results into a dense matrix without performing an intermediate conversion step?

Comment: In the first case, why not simply convert the result of the sparse matrix multiplication to a dense matrix? Example: `sp_fmat A = S_a*S_b; fmat B(A);`  In the second case, the result of sparse*dense is already dense. Example: `fmat C = S_a*D;`

Comment: @mtall Because that's an extra step of unnecessary overhead. These matrices are of the order 100,000s in size, so it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mat` constructor which takes a sparse matrix and converts its data to a dense one:

```
arma::mat out1(S_a * S_b);
arma::mat out2(S_b * D);
```

Both multiplication operators for the sparse class (sparse-sparse and sparse-dense) will produce a sparse matrix object as output. (Whether or not it's really sparse will depend on the structure of the inputs.) This can be converted to a dense matrix using the dense matrix constructor with signature: `arma::mat(arma::sp_mat)`.